# How to Select Certain Number of Rows occurring after a particular character using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, select, row

I have an exported worksheet that contains 3 useless rows (containing useless text) sandwiched between two cells containing "------------" each, after a differing number of rows of useful data.The occurrence of those useless rows is not uniform meaning at some points, they occur after 8 rows of useful data, sometimes after 9, etc.

I need to remove those useless rows but the worksheet is quite large. So, I must use VBA to solve this problem.

Being a beginner, I have written following code as per my best capability:

Application.ActiveSheet.Select("------------")

Range(Selection).Rows(1:3).Delete

But it does not work.

Please guide me on following 2 points:

1. How can I select 3 rows occurring between two cells containing "------------" (apostrophes are not actually in the cells; they are just for you)?
2. Can I delete those selected rows using delete keyword or do I need something else?

Thanks for help.

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can locate first cell containing `------------` using MATCH, store that value into a variable and then just delete from that target row and next 4 rows (so you'll delete first `------------`, 3 not useful rows and second `------------`). Something like `Rows(i & ":" & i+4).Delete`

Comment: Show how it looks in the spreadsheet. Is there one such block of rows to delete in each sheet, or are there multiple blocks? Should these  cells with "----" also be removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the macro below. It will delete all rows where any value in that row contains a minimum of 3 dashes "---". However, you can change the minimum number of -'s to whatever you need.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set WS = ActiveSheet

For i = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1

If WS.Cells(i, i).Value Like "*---*" Then WS.Cells(i, i).EntireRow.Delete

Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

- When deleting rows and causing lower rows to shift, it's crucial to iterate in reverse order to avoid potential issues with the shifting.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.EntireRow property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirerow?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144123)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, arrData
    Dim LastRow As Long, sFlag As String
    Const CHR_CNT = 12 ' count of "-"
    Const ROW_CNT = 3 ' countt of deleted rows
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arrData = Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value
    sFlag = Application.Rept("-", CHR_CNT)
    For i = UBound(arrData) To LBound(arrData) + 3 Step -1
        If arrData(i, 1) = sFlag And arrData(i - ROW_CNT - 1, 1) = sFlag Then
            Debug.Print i - ROW_CNT - 1
            Cells(i - ROW_CNT - 1, 1).Resize(ROW_CNT + 2).EntireRow.Delete
            i = i - ROW_CNT - 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

Option 2:

- Collect all useless rows as a range object (delRng)
- Delete rows all at once

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.Union method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm132112)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub Demo2()
    Dim i As Long, arrData, delRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, sFlag As String
    Const CHR_CNT = 12 ' count of "-"
    Const ROW_CNT = 3 ' countt of deleted rows
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arrData = Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value
    sFlag = Application.Rept("-", CHR_CNT)
    For i = UBound(arrData) To LBound(arrData) + 3 Step -1
        If arrData(i, 1) = sFlag And arrData(i - ROW_CNT - 1, 1) = sFlag Then
            If delRng Is Nothing Then
                Set delRng = Cells(i - ROW_CNT - 1, 1).Resize(ROW_CNT + 2)
            Else
                Set delRng = Application.Union(delRng, Cells(i - ROW_CNT - 1, 1).Resize(ROW_CNT + 2))
            End If
            i = i - ROW_CNT - 1
        End If
    Next i
    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

[image]